# Enviar e-mail via c#

Tags: c#, sendmail

Boa tarde,

Eu estou precisando enviar e-mail via c#, ai para teste, queria saber quais são as credenciais do outlook/hotmail para enviar e-mails

Comment: Você não tem as credenciais?

Comment: O que seriam as credenciais, meu e-mail e senha do outlook ou as credenciais dentro do smtp? Dentro do outlook não tenho

Comment: Outra coisa, no php eu sei que o mail só funciona hospedado, no c# também se mantém essa regra?

Comment: O host correto do smtp não seria `smtp-mail.outlook.com`?

Comment: Leandro, as credenciais é o usuário e senha normalmente como se fosse fazer login através do client da microsoft ou google

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma maneira de envio de e-mails. Utiliza-se como credenciais o login e a senha que você utiliza para logar na sua conta.

```
 try
        {
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp_aqui",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("seu_e_mail", "sua_senha")
            };
            using (var smtpMessage = new MailMessage("seu_e_mail", "e_mail_destino"))
            {
                smtpMessage.Subject = "assunto";
                smtpMessage.Body = "Corpo";
                smtpMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
                smtp.Send(smtpMessage);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //todo: add logging integration
            //throw;
        }
```

Comment: o smtp do c# funciona sem hospedar ou tem que estar hospedado igual no php?

Comment: Não sei como funciona no php. Como um exemplo utilizando o smtp do gmail ficaria (smtp.gmail.com)

Comment: Eu digo que o sistema precisa estar hospedado para funcionar no php, acredito que isso também aconteça no c#

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso um serviço Free (até um certo limite de e-mails, mas é alto!) chamado SendGrid (utilizando o Nuget do SendGrid).
* Não estou fazendo propaganda , apenas gosto e recomendo o serviço, me ajuda muito. E você não fica amarrado em credenciais de seu provedor, usa a API dos caras, e dá pra monitorar os emails enviados, os que deram erro para delivery etc!

e o código fica muito mais simples:

Segue:

```
public static async Task Send(Email email)
{
    var apiKey = SendGridAPIKey;
    var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
    var from = new EmailAddress("no-reply@provider.com", "Name");
    var subject = email.Subject;
    var to = new EmailAddress(email.AddressTo, "User");
    var plainTextContent = email.Message;
    var htmlContent = email.Message;
    var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
    var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
}
```

Pacote Nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/

Site:
https://sendgrid.com/

Comment: Pode ter certeza que eu vou dar uma olhada nele

Comment: Amigo, bom dia, está dando erro no aplkey

Cannot convert from 'object' to 'SendGrid.SendGridOptions.'

Comment: O APIKey é uma String, que você deve pegar no site do Sendgrid.